# Pass arguments to controller methods

Tags: php, symfony, controller, silex

I'm using silex and I'm trying to use controllers as services. This conception works fine but I can't figure out how to pass arguments to controller method. Here is what I mean

IndexController.php

```
class IndexController
{
  public function pagesAction($page)
  {
    return $page;
  }
}
```

//app.php

```
$app['index.controller'] = $app->share(function() use ($app) {
       return new Controllers\IndexController();
     });
 $app->get('/pages/{num}', "index.controller:pagesAction");
```

When I access pages/3 I get

```
Controller "SD\Controllers\IndexController::pagesAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$page" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).
```

I also tried

```
$app->get('/pages/{num}', "index.controller:pagesAction:num");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not familiar with silex but try changing $page to $num in your controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
class IndexController
{
  public function pagesAction($page) //what is $page? Is not into route
  {
    return $page;
  }
}
```

to

```
class IndexController
{
  public function pagesAction($num)
  {
    return $page;
  }
}
```

This is because silex (and is also Symfony2 logic, of course) expects arguments name to be exactly the same from route to controller

## OR

you should change your route to be parametrized for `$page` variable